# Doctrine inner query set parameters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to execute an inner query and set parameters without success, i always get:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

This is my query :

```
SELECT i2
FROM MyBundle:Identity i2
INNER JOIN MyBundle:Property\\Mapped\\Email propertyEmail WITH propertyEmail.identity = i2
INNER JOIN MyBundle:Channel channel WITH propertyEmail.channel = channel
WHERE ( 
    SELECT COUNT(mappedEmail)
    FROM MyBundle:Property\\Mapped\\Email mappedEmail
    WHERE mappedEmail.identity = i2  
    AND mappedEmail.channel = :channel 
    AND mappedEmail.createdAt <= :dateFrom
 ) > 0  
 AND IDENTITY(propertyEmail.channel) <> :channel
 AND propertyEmail.createdAt <= :dateFrom
 GROUP BY i2
```

And this is how i put as subquery:

```
$innerQuery = $queryBuilder->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query)
    ->setParameters([
        'channel' => $channelId,                             
        'dateFrom' => $dateFrom
    ])
;
$queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn($alias, $innerQuery->getDQL()));
```

That return the error :

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

If I execute the query as single query all works right.
Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: try adding the parameters on the last querybuilder NOT on the inner one

Answer (score 2):

Try to apply the parameters to the main query as follow:

```
$innerQuery = $queryBuilder->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query);

$queryBuilder
 ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn($alias, $innerQuery->getDQL()))
  ->setParameters([
        'channel' => $channelId,                             
        'dateFrom' => $dateFrom
    ]);
```